# Elevated Ayin (ע) in Iyov 38:13 and 38:15

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, safrus, job-iyov-book-of

I noticed this in [Iyov 38:13,15](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2738.htm):

> יג  לֶאֱחֹז, בְּכַנְפוֹת הָאָרֶץ;    וְיִנָּעֲרוּ רְשָׁ<sup>עִ</sup>ים מִמֶּנָּה.‏
>   טו  וְיִמָּנַע מֵרְשָׁ<sup>עִ</sup>ים אוֹרָם;    וּזְרוֹעַ רָמָה, תִּשָּׁבֵר.‏

I [know about unusual letter forms](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18402/is-the-winding-%D7%A4-in-this-sefer-torah-kosher). Why is this letter in particular elevated?

Comment: Tehillim 80:14 and Shoftim 18:30 are the other two places where this phenomenon is observed ([a priori, that is](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85456/759))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Talmud Sanhedrin 103b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.103b)

> אמר ר"ש בן לקיש מאי דכתיב (איוב לח, טו) וימנע מרשעים אורם וזרוע רמה תשבר מפני מה עי"ן של רשעים תלויה כיון שנעשה אדם רש מלמטה נעשה רש מלמעלה
>   ולא נכתביה כלל ר' יוחנן ור"א חד אמר מפני כבודו של דוד וחד אמר משום כבודו של נחמיה בן חכליה
>
> **Rabbi Shimon ben Lakish says: What** is the meaning of that **which is written: “And He will withhold their light from the wicked [resha’im], and the high arm shall be broken” (Job 38:15)? For what** reason is the letter ***ayin* of** the word ***resha’im* suspended** slightly above the rest of the letters? It is suspended so that the word will be read rashim, meaning poor people. It means: **Once a person becomes poor** on earth **below** and the number of his enemies grows, **he becomes poor** in Heaven **above**, as he is certainly a sinner and that is why he is hated.
>   The Gemara challenges: If that is the meaning, **let** the ayin **not be written at all** and let the verse say: Rashim. **Rabbi Yoḥanan and Rabbi Elazar** both explain why the ayin was not omitted. **One says:** It was **due to** the desire to preserve **the honor of David**, who had numerous enemies below despite the fact that he was a righteous person and had a place in the World-to-Come. **And one says:** It was **due to** the desire to preserve **the honor of Nehemiah, son of Hacaliah,** who also had numerous enemies below, despite his righteousness.