# How to find the date of my ancestors' Torah Scroll?

Tags: sefer-torah

This Sefer Torah has been in my family for many generations. From what I am told by my great-uncles, this manuscript could date back several centuries but the work of dating it has never been formally done. Since the death of my grandfather, who brought the sefer from Tunisia where the family had a synagogue it is stored in a synagogue in the Paris suburbs. The sefer is not used for prayer because, according to the rabbis, it is not kosher.

Is it possible based on written layout and style to get an idea of how old is this Sefer Torah?
I can provide more pictures if needed.

Edit 1: I added a picture with what seem to be a replaced column, maybe this will help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to my great uncles it could be from the XV century. I am descendent of Or Ha-Haim Ben Attar

Comment: "Is it possible based on written layout and style to get an idea of how old is this Sefer Torah?" There indeed are expert paleographers who can do this. The general answer is ask them. (As regards this particular example, there's no way this is 15th century. I'd say it's pretty late premodern sefardi. I can send these to a friend of a friend see what he thinks.)

Comment: @DoubleAA what geographic regions do you think of when you say "late premodern Sefardi"?

Comment: @DoubleAA I added three more pictures (including the case)

Comment: To add to what DoubleAA wrote, some of the things an expert may look at is how many lines per column, whether certain letters are elongated  in order to justify the margins, the form of certain letters etc... all this is analyzed by light of when certain practices are known to have become more or less widespread and/or standardized. Another method would of course be radio-carbon dating. I certainly hope you manage to find someone that can help you with this, because it seems that you have something very precious and special. I pray that all efforts are made to preserve it as best as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much @Deuteronomy, one thing we know is that in 1725 my family moved from Gibraltar to Tunisia for unknown reasons, and the “legend” says that they took with them two Torah scrolls.

Comment: As it's pasul, you might want to consider a carbon-14 test to date the scroll itself, which would likely be more or less the time the sefer was made. And for paleographical dating, there are paleographers around the world, so try contacting one that specializes in Jewish texts, and particular those who specialize in Sifrei Torah or Jewish manuscripts from Tunisia.

Comment: My friend's friend said (just based on the picture without knowing any your family history from Tunisia) that it's unquestionably Tunisian but not too early. Given your story, we can say pretty confidently that it's around 200 +/-  years old or so and not brought from Gibraltar.

Comment: @Harel13 It's not obviously pasul (or certainly not obviously enough that someone couldn't touch it up), but anyway an invalid scroll still has sanctity. Carbon dating involves cutting off a piece and burning it (to analyze the ash) which is quite halachichly problematic.

Comment: cc @Deuteronomy (there are many more things to look at too, including the type of gvil/klaf and even the stitching)

Comment: @DoubleAA absolutely, by no means an exhaustive list

Comment: @DoubleAA This is incredible. We did some research on my family ancestors, in 1725 Rav Shlomo Ben Attar came in Tunisia. We would like to bring this Sefer to Israel (where I live now) do you think we could renovate it and then make it kosher?

Comment: @Ben1725 I would be very hesitant to make any changes to it and very careful about who is chosen to do so if you are insistent on going in that direction. It is possible that a sofer who tries to update a sefer torah to bring it in line with many contemporary norms and practices of safruth will in the process eradicate various of its unique features that were deemed perfectly acceptable by the original users of the Torah.

Comment: @Deuteronomy so you suggest not touching it? I agree with you but it means that it can’t be used for prayers. Then I am not sure where it should be.

Comment: @Ben1725 I would be very careful to choose someone that will restore it to its original state, rather than "restore it" by means of changing it to bring it in line with contemporary practice... hopefully someone can chime in with a recommendation about who to approach with such a task. Just my 2¢

Comment: @Deuteronomy understood. It makes sense. Seems like it will be a long and difficult task to only find the right Sofer - but might be worth it. Out of curiosity, are 200-300 years old Sefer Torah common? Does it have a special religious meaning or only the fact that it is kosher matters? Sorry for all those questions but it is fascinating and you are being very helpful.

Comment: 200-300 year old sifre torah are not altogether uncommon. The age doesn't inherently add any "special religious meaning" but I wouldn't discount the psychology of holding onto and continuing to using a Torah that one knows their ancestors or their community's ancestors have held onto and used through thick and thin. As for its status of being "kosher" - there are obviously different standards (as with all other areas of halakhah) about what is fit or unfit for use - but yes, certainly if a specific community is using it, then the standards of that community would have to be met in order to use

Comment: I would also add, that I don't want you to think I have any particular expertise in this area... these are just some things I've picked up over the years through learning. As always, consulting in person with someone you deem competent is of utmost importance.

Comment: @DoubleAA Shavua Tov. I know an invalid sefer still has sanctity. C14 nowadays involves picking out a very miniscule piece. Perhaps there would be some heter. I don't know whether this has ever been discussed by poskim, but it may be worth looking into.

Comment: @Harel13 if the cost is reasonable and this would not impact the Sefer then we would definitely do it. Now I am on a mission to find a Sofer who can give a quote for restoring it without denaturing it. I will start looking in Israel.

Comment: As a follow-up, we asked multiple paleographers to provide feedback on the Sefer Torah, and they reached a consensus that it dates back to the 19th century. The Torah Scroll has been moved and brought to a Sofer. We now have an album containing most of the parts, and according to the Sofer, we will be able to restore it. I can share the full album upon request. @DoubleAA

Comment: @JohnJohnGa Nice. Perhaps you could summarize your findings in an answer, ideally with tips for future people in similar predicaments and/or any info the paleographers gave about what led them to that conclusion. You can always update as you learn new things.

Comment: @DoubleAA I will do this hopefully next week.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a sofer but I have seen various Torah scrolls and own a column of a scroll from Tunisia. In my experience, Tunisian scrolls tend to have a writing style close to Moroccan. The Moroccan writing style typically has thicker block letters than other Sephardic scrolls, AND their [Het's look normal/flat and don't look like two zayins put together like most other Sephardic scrolls nowadays](http://lavlor.blogspot.com/2009/03/rashi-vs-rabbeinu-tam-round-1.html).

[How to Write Chets in Moroccan Tradition](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=How_To_Write_Letters_in_a_Sefer_Torah,_Tefillin,_and_Mezuzot&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop#Chet_-_(%D7%97))

I would agree with @DoubleAA's comment that this scroll looks like a lot of other more modern Sephardic scrolls, but not specifically from Tunisia. Or if it is from Tunisia, I would date it to be within the past few hundred years as during this time most Sepharadim were transitioning to the pyramid chet of Rabbeinu Tam.

To see examples of other scrolls from Tunisia you can see some on Ebay here:
https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p4432023.m570.l1313&_nkw=torah+scroll+tunisia&_sacat=0

I would reach out to a competent sofer who has a history of repairing older Sephardic scrolls so they can help you date it. It's certainly possible that the scroll is from Tunisia, but perhaps the sofer who wrote it was trained by a different tradition than I'm used to seeing if the scroll is as old as your family narrative states.

Comment: the Torah pictured above actually does have flat חיתי׳׳ן!

Comment: It's very inconsistent and the pyramid chet sticks out to me most often. But you're right, it does have flat chet's sometimes, which I believe is the older sephardic custom

Comment: @Aaron If you look at Edit 1, you will see a picture with what seems to be a replaced column

Comment: Even many moroccans started doing a rabbenu tam chet at some point. See comments on answer that this was identified by an expert as unquestionably tunisian.

Comment: @DoubleAA Most Sepharadim and now even many Yemenites have moved onto the Pyramid Chet of Rebeinu Tam. But in terms of Moroccan and Tunisian Torah scrolls from hundreds of years ago, in my personal non professional experience they have the flat Chets.