How to find provenance of Megillah klaf
I was cleaning out my Zayde's z"l house in Baltimore and found an old Megillat Ester klaf hidden in a drawer.
We are wondering if anyone knows if there are ways to date the scroll and tell its nusach/ketav and other information about it.
Edit: so far I believe that this is written in ketav Arizal with the Baal Shem Tov's peh, so according to a source I saw on Sefaria, it was written sometimes in the late 18th century or 19th century. There are 42 lines per column.
Possibly helpful information: The scroll is about 21 inches long. My Zayde was born in Baltimore in 1920, his parents were born in the 1880s near the city of Lomze, Poland, and came to American in the early 20th century. There is also some Sephardic heritage, with one of his grandparents moving to Poland from Turkey.



Edit: zoomed in pictures




https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139719/how-to-find-the-date-of-my-ancestors-torah-scroll/139731#comment466725_139719 That said it is highly unlikely there is anything so unique about this scroll besides "about a hundred years ago european ashkenazi"

Start with a high quality close up the letters. No one can tell almost anything from these pictures

@DoubleAA more pictures added. Just knowing that it is a normal 100 year old Askenazi scroll is interesting to me!

Ask a sofer, or Jewish scribe. They are probably most knowledgeable, and could maybe direct you to historians who specialize in graphology.
